# juju controller bootstrap failure on MAAS node added on ESXi VM?

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack, cloud

I am trying to deploy open-stack with juju and MAAS following the open-stack docs https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/rocky/install-juju.html

My environment is consists of 5*VMs on ESXi 6.5:

1*VM for MAAS_2.5

1*VM for juju controller

4*VM for openstack

I am able from MAAS node to manage all the other VMs: commission, deploy, power off/on "power type is VMware",

[maas nodes status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSqv8.png)

but when I tried to bootstrap juju 
controller on corresponding VM I've got bellow error:

```
root@juju-client:~/.local/share/juju# juju bootstrap --constraints tags=juju mymaas maas-controller
Creating Juju controller "maas-controller" on mymaas
Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.5.1 for amd64
Launching controller instance(s) on mymaas...
ERROR failed to bootstrap model: cannot start bootstrap instance in availability zone "default": failed to acquire node: No available machine matches constraints: [('agent_name', ['0fa73fcb-3ca7-49a5-88f0-67efc062a3fd']), ('mem', ['3584']), ('tags', ['juju']), ('zone', ['default'])] (resolved to "mem=3584.0 tags=juju zone=default")
```

All nodes are in ready state on MAAS. I've tried to bootstrap juju controller on physical server with same MAAS node "which is VM" and have no such problem.

So did I miss anything or there is some special configuration or it is a bug when deploying MAAS/juju on ESXi VMs; and what is the solution?

Too many reported this problem without any robust solution or clear explanation? anyone can help with it please.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you do not have any machine in MAAS for juju ….
Try this work arround… Create a machine with 4GB Ram and 2 CPUS..

If this not work please tell me...

KR

Comment: I have a VM with required specification (4GB of RAM and 2 CPUs ...) and it is in ready state, but MAAS can't provide it to bootstrap juju controller even I am able to deploy normal ubuntu image from MAAS on it.